# Скачка csv с сервера

Tags: php

Есть проблема: на хостинге лежит файл .csv, при открытии в браузере он его открывает как текст, а нужно, чтобы предлагал сохранить или открыть. Как такое сделать?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вопрос решен! Прописал заголовки и все нормально.